# How to append data on every span and div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

How to append data to every span and div using javascript

```
$(document).on("click",".selection-state",function(){
            stateid = $(this).attr("rel");

                    $("#my_tooltip").html(data);
                } else {
                    get_state_wise_districts(stateid,statename);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: There is append data in error.

Comment: strchr(): search for a character in a C string (i.e. char *)
strtok(): splits a C string into substrings, based on a separator character
atoi(): converts a C string to an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `append()` instead of `html()`:

```
$(document).on("click",".selection-state",function(){ 
         stateid = $(this).attr("rel");
         $("#my_tooltip").append(data);
     } else {
          get_state_wise_districts(stateid,statename);
     }
});
```